# Eclipse Luna crashes on new project in Ubuntu

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, crash

I'm having some trouble getting Eclipse Luna to work. I downloaded the tar.gz from the eclipse site and I downloaded the tar.gz for the Java JDK. I extracted everything and Eclipse opens properly, but when I try to make a new project, it crashes on me. In the terminal I ran `java -version` and it tells me I have version 1.8.0_25 so I don't think I have an issue with java. Now, this happens if I try to make any kind of project. Eclipse opens the wizard for creating a new project of a particular type and then the whole application crashes. When I started doing this, I installed it under the KDE desktop. When Eclipse crashes, I get the message  `java: /build/buildd/gtk2-engines-oxygen-1.4.5/src/animations/oxygencomboboxdata.cpp:87‌​: void Oxygen::ComboBoxData::setButton(GtkWidget*): Assertion '!_button._widget' failed`. So, I decided to install the xfce desktop to get around it, since oxygen is a KDE theme. I uninstalled eclipse and reinstalled it under xfce and I have the same behavior and the same errors. When I run eclipse from the command line, I get this exception on startup:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxConfiguration$1 cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogHelper.logJavaProperties(LogHelper.java:26)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.loadConfiguration(LogPlugin.java:189)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.configureLogback(LogPlugin.java:144)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin.access$2(LogPlugin.java:107)
at org.eclipse.m2e.logback.configuration.LogPlugin$1.run(LogPlugin.java:62)
at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Does anyone have any ideas on what else to try?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

According to comment 20 in this bug report: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440660#c20

> This seems to be a bug in GTK according to
> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gtk2-engines-oxygen/+bug/1242801
> (there a similar problem for Meld was reported).
>
> Another workaround mentioned there is for Oxygen, edit the normally already existing file
> `/usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc` and change
>
> ```
> `GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 1`
> ```
>
> into
>
> ```
> `GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 0`
> ```
>
> This workaround is working for me.

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. This was driving me nuts.

Comment: @Cerin yeah me too, I was so fed up with it that I kept googling until I found a solution. This SO answer is my most popular SO answer! :)

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved this issue by installing package `gtk2-engines-oxygen` built for Ubuntu Vivid Vervet (version 1.4.6):

http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/gtk2-engines-oxygen

Comment: On Ubuntu Trusty, this apparently requires upgrading libc: `gtk2-engines-oxygen:amd64 depends on libstdc++6 (>= 4.9); however:
  Version of libstdc++6:amd64 on system is 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.`  However, switching to a non-oxygen theme and simply removing gtk2-engines-oxygen seems to work.