# ggts 3.6.4 does not work

Tags: grails, ubuntu-14.04, ggts

the today release of ggts 3.6.4 does not work.
After starting with an empty workspace and trying
file, new, grailsProject
ggts vanishes with no error message.
same problem in ggts 3.6.2/3 I keep working with 3.6.1
I'm using ubuntu 14.4, maybe that's the problem

peter,
Dortmund, Germany

Comment: start it on command line and see if there are errors and/or check, if there are logs in your installation directory. then add them here, or report it to the vendor.

Comment: java: /build/buildd/gtk2-engines-oxygen-1.4.5/src/animations/oxygencomboboxdata.cpp:87: void Oxygen::ComboBoxData::setButton(GtkWidget*): Zusicherung »!_button._widget« nicht erfüllt.

Comment: I struggled with this myself a while back and reverted to 3.6.1. There wasn't anything useful (to me anyway) in the logs or stdout output when starting from the commandline. I doubt there's all that much different between this version and the latest. I suppose I'll try again with 4.0 and 3.7 if there is one.

Comment: a workaround can be find here:

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/537216/eclipse-luna-crashes-on-new-project-in-kubuntu-14-04

Comment: I changed kubuntu system settings from oxygen to aurora, which has a differnt look but it works

Comment: see the comment on the answer there.  you can change the theme per app via envvar in GTK.  i always had to do this with theme color intrusive apps like eclipse.  so no need to change the whole system.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26436009/eclipse-luna-crashes-on-new-project-in-ubuntu this is related to user364703 posting - I ended up edit the normally already existing file /usr/share/themes/oxygen-gtk/gtk-2.0/gtkrc and change

`GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 1`

into

`GtkComboBox::appears-as-list = 0`

Comment: Pivotal says, this would be the last version of GGTS